# Powershell Script to Copy Files to new Destination

Tags: powershell

I'm using the below powershell script to move files from $Source to $Destination based on a date range.  During testing, it's moving all of files within a directory that may have been updated within the date range, but I only require the updated or new files with the Directory/Subdirectory. I like how it's working, except for copying everything.

Any thoughts on how the script can can be tweaked?

```
$source = "C:\Documents and Settings"
$destination = "C:\Documents and Settings\Test"
[datetime]$start = '2/18/2021 11:00:00'
[datetime]$end = '2/18/2021 11:15:00'

 #Prod
 dir $source | %{ dir $_.FullName | ?{ $_.LastWriteTime -gt $start-and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $end } | 
 Copy-Item -Destination $destination -Recurse -Force }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you probably need to do, if you're staying in Powershell and not using something like Robocopy to sync the folders, would be to push the path recursion up a level and then check a file at a time:

1. `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` on the source path
2. `ForEach-Object` on the result
3. `Test-Path` on the destination (doing a `Replace` of `$source` to `$destination` in the path)
4. `Copy-Item` from `$source` to `$destination` where the file doesn't exist or the `LastFileWrite` property is newer at the source path

Answer (score 1):

In Posh, you filter as far left for faster results.

```
$source = "C:\Documents and Settings"
$destination = "C:\Documents and Settings\Test"
[datetime]$start = '2/18/2021 11:00:00'
[datetime]$end = '2/18/2021 11:15:00'

Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.lastwriteTime -le $start -lt $end } | ForEach-Object -Process { Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $destination -Force }
```

You're doing redundant work when you pipe another `dir` down the line.

Comment: This gets files between the `$start` and `$end` dates, but it doesn't copy only files that are new or changed.

Comment: Does assigning the paths returned to a variable make a difference?

Comment: wait, im confused now... so you DONT want to copy the files in between your `$start` and `$end` variables?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I read the original post as "copy files between `$start` and `$end` dates, where the file does not already exist in `$destination`, or the file in `$source` is newer"?

Comment: I only want to copy files to the $destination that have been modified or if the file is new between $start and $end dates

Comment: have been modified within the last 30 minutes? or just in general?

Comment: @Abraham..in general between date/time range. Example could be between 1/1/2021 00:00:00 and 1/30/2021 23:59:59. This could capture .lastmodified, .created,.lastfilewrite; I'm still testing to see with function performs the desired results.